# Create new file containing filename and count each file

Tags: shell, unix, sh, ksh

I need to create a new `file_count.txt` containing  filename and line count.

Directory Structure

```
$ find asia emea -name \*.gz   
asia/2013/emp_asia_13.txt.gz  
asia/2015/emp_asia_15.txt.gz  
asia/2014/emp_asia_14.txt.gz  
emea/2013/emp_emea_13.txt.gz  
emea/2015/emp_emea_15.txt.gz  
emea/2014/emp_emea_14.txt.gz
```

The output file should be like:

```
emp_asia_13.txt.gz 20  
emp_asia_15.txt.gz 15  
emp_asia_14.txt.gz 50  
emp_emea_13.txt.gz 32  
emp_emea_15.txt.gz 26  
emp_emea_14.txt.gz 70
```

Comment: I suppose you want the line counts of the `.txt` files once they have been decompressed?

Comment: Do you have `zcat` or do we need to use `gunzip -c`?

Comment: i think zcat will wok.i am usually using zcat filename | wc -l for each file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution using a *for* loop**

```
for file in $(find asia emea -name \*.gz -print0 | xargs -0)
do
    echo -n $(basename $file);
    gunzip -c $file |wc -l;
done >> file_count.txt
```

In one line, it gives:

```
$ for file in $(find asia emea -name \*.gz -print0 | xargs -0); do echo -n $(basename $file); gunzip -c $file |wc -l; done >> file_count.txt
```

And the output is:

```
$ cat file_count.txt
emp_asia_13.txt.gz       4
emp_asia_14.txt.gz      10
emp_emea_15.txt.gz      17
```

Comment: I added another solution that provides the output expected, if you don't mind the tabulations. If the solution satisfies you, you should mark the question as answered.

Comment: Are you sure about the -c options ? At least in my ubuntu  "=l" is the option to be used. "-c" shows lots of data on screen

Comment: i think output is as per my requirement :)

Comment: How does `find -print0 | xargs -0` help?  You might as well just use the default `find -print`.  (But of course you should use `-exec sh -c ...`).  You're still subjecting the result of the command substitution to word splitting and glob expansion, as part of evaluating the `for file in ...`.  And you don't even quote `"$file"` on gunzip's command line.  So you have some good ideas, but this will break with filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try:

```
find asia emea -type f -name "*gz" | while IFS= read -r fname; do
    printf "%s %s\n" "$fname" $(gzip -dc "$fname" | wc -l) >> file_count.txt
done
```

which as a 1-liner would be:

```
find asia emea -type f -name "*gz" | while IFS= read -r fname; do printf "%s %s\n" "$fname" $(gzip -dc "$fname" | wc -l) >> file_count.txt; done
```

Comment: Don't forget `IFS= ` to avoid stripping leading/trailing whitespace from filenames.  Or see my answer for a couple ways to do it that don't break even on filenames containing newline.

Comment: Good point. I rarely in my own scripts worry about *not* stripping leading/trailing whitespace from filenames, because all filenames on my filesystem are *sane*. But for the wider-world, that can't be presumed...

Comment: same here.  My one-liners are often "fairly" safe, even though I don't need them to be.  I got interested in improving the code in bash-completions a few months ago, and rigorous shell-safety is *hard*.  Esp. for completions, where the completion-generator is a command that takes pattern args and produces output that you want to read into an array...

Comment: Yes, I always look for new tools to add to my bash toolbox and do try and concentrate on dotting all `i`'s and `t`'s, but after 100 local uses of just get the job done, the  `i`'s and `t`'s seem to fade from the forefront of the old gray matter. Thanks for the reminder... again...

Comment: I always wonder what poor sucker has a filesystem full of files with paragraph-long filenames, newlines and all.  I usually ignore newline-safety with shell code, because it's often really inconvenient, if not impossible.  For my own interactive one-off use, sometimes it's easier to use a `$(cmd substitution)` instead of piping into `read` when I know the filenames are clean.  In fact, I don't usually end up piping into `read` for my own interactive use at all.  More often I use `for i in *some_fancy_extglob*` or `find -exec`.

Comment: The poor sap is usually a Linux sysadmin, who supports a windows workforce via samba shares and ends up with a holy-mess of nonsensical filenames that only a scrabble board could love. When I built the first Linux backend for my office in '99, I put a file-name formatting sheet at all the workstations just to prevent that nonsense. How some people will just start typing a novel in the file-save dialog is beyond me, but alas, many haven't been around since the days of dual-floppies either...

Answer (score 1):

To run shell stuff on the results of `find` in a way that doesn't break on any special characters, you can use `find -exec sh -c ...`.  (see below).

In this case, you don't really need that, if you can use bash's `extglob` to match in subdirectories for you.  I just realized this is a `ksh` question, and IDK if it has something equivalent.

```
shopt -s extglob
for i in {asia,emea}/**/*.gz;do
    bn=${i##*/}  # basename
    printf "%s %s\n" "$bn"  "$(zcat "$i"|wc -l)"   # stolen from David's answer
done > linecounts.txt  # redirect once outside the loop.
```

This is like David's answer, except it will successfully count lines even in files with names containing a newline.  The output file will be a mess, though, because newline is the usual record separator for textual data, so having it in filenames is just asking for trouble.

If you know your directory structure, you don't need extglob and can just use `*/*/*.gz`.  Optionally with some leading characters to cut off some subdir searches.  (bash isn't as smart as find when traversing directories, either.  It always `stat`s everything to see if it's a directory, even on filesystems that fill in the `d_type` field in [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) results.)

Note that with extglob, you *do* need `dir/**/*.gz`, not just `dir/**.gz`

---

More generally, you can use `find` with `xargs` and shell commands by having xargs run `sh -c`, and then inside that `-c`, loop over the positional paramaters.  `for i` does that implicitly; i.e. it's equivalent to `for i in "$@"`.

```
find -name '*.gz` -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c 'for i in "$@";do ...loop body from above...;done > linecounts.txt' bash
```

You can simplify this to having `find` run `sh -c` itself, if you have a `find` that supports the `+` terminator for `-exec` (to put a list of matches onto one command line):

```
find -name '*.gz` -exec bash -c 'for i in "$@";do ...loop body from above...;done > linecounts.txt' bash {} +
```

In both cases, **you need a dummy arg** before the args from `find` or `xargs`, because that will end up as argv[0] (traditionally the command name).